# Closing many RabbitMQ channels simultaneously in multiple threads... long pause

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have 1 RabbitMQ Connection, 10K publishing Channels, 10K consuming Channels and 100 Threads. All channels are in rapid publish/consume "loops" using exclusive queues and external synchronization; no possibility of publish, consume or close happening simultaneously on a channel. Closing channels simultaneously on 100 threads incurs a 
delay of 2.5 seconds for each of the first 100 channels. All subsequent closures are processed in less than 0.5 seconds. If I bump it up to 20K+20K channels the initial 100 each take 5 seconds to close. With 30K+30K each takes 10 seconds, where we're pretty much at the channel-max for a connection. Similarly if I reduce the number of threads to 50 then it's the first 50 channels that close slowly.

Let me restate that... **With 30K+30K channels the first 100 each take 10 seconds to close using 100 simultaneous threads. The remaining 59,900 each take less than 0.5 seconds.** My feeling is that there's some funky connection-wide synchronization/continuation going on here. Hit the connection up with 100 channel-close requests on 100 threads simultaneously and it baulks. Whatever causes that initial spasm doesn't seem to affect subsequent close operations and everything swims along nicely.

I've tried ramping up the number of connections to relieve the pressure. This certainly works with predictable results. With 30K+30K connections spread evenly over 2 connections the initial 100 channel-close delays are halved from 10 seconds to 5 seconds. Use 10 connections and the delay is imperceptible when compared to the subsequent 59,900 channel closures. Jump to 50K+50K channels (we can do this with 10 connections but not 1 connection due to channel-max) and the delays start to creep back in again.

My concerns with this approach are that 1) multiple connections are discouraged in the documentation due to i/o resource overhead and that 2) it's not clear for my application how to sensibly predict the optimum number of channels per connection. If there is a soft limit to the number of channels per connection why is it not documented or made available in the api? If I have to manage a number of connections and allocate channels across those connections in a robust manner I feel like I'm doing the work of a client library!

I've tried my hand at modifying the client library by not waiting for channel-close acknowledgements from the RabbitMQ server. This worked like a charm. Channels were closed instantly with no delay in the client and confirmed as closed on the server. Eight hours later though and I was out of heap space as the channel resources internal to the client library were not being released. I haven't managed to isolate the source of the delay either... is it in the client library or the server itself? To progress further I'd need to trace the wire protocol. I think I'm off track with this approach!

**Questions:**

Before making application changes I'd like to know if this is a known issue with the Java client? Are there better workarounds than multiple connections and application-level channel management? In practise my actual application uses around 20K channels per process, which I don't feel is excessive, and message throughput is actually pretty light as I'm leveraging RabbitMQ more for the routing. I could even live with the delays but they're already noticeable. I could refactor to use less channels but then I'd be sharing channels and would either have to synchronize their usage or ignore documentation guidelines. The error handling paradigm makes this cumbersome though; any channel error results in it's termination so it's difficult to isolate errors, prevent them from permeating and recover in a robust manner.

**Detail:**

RabbitMQ server 3.1.5, Java amqp-client 3.1.5. Also tried 3.1.4, 3.1.3 in the same test harness and seen what I assume to be exactly the same behaviour in 3.0 and prior in production application.

My test harness is standalone but a bit obtuse to post here. I create 10K test clients each of which creates an exclusive queue and runs a continuous publish-consume-publish-consume loop. The publisher and consumer each have their own channels. I'm using channel.basicConsume with DefaultConsumers and a default consumer executor service. Also used my own Java executor service, which appears to be the same as the default implementation, with various numbers of threads to no discernible effect.

Messages consumed in handleDelivery spawn a new publish task via a java.concurrent fixed thread pool, so the consumer thread is not tied up or used in any channel operations whatsoever. The channel-close is synchronized so that it cannot happen at the same time as a publish. However there's nothing stopping a consume happening while close is being processed - the consumer is out of my control.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: It's probably better to discuss this on the RabbitMQ mailing list http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/

Comment: Thanks @Carl, posted with sourcecode http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Long-pauses-when-closing-many-channels-simultaneously-tp29937.html